# python setuptool multiple package arrangement

Tags: python, setuptools

In the same repository, I would like to build two packages, `ns.foo` and `ns.bar` under namespace `ns`.  But after many tries, it seems the only way this can work is to put them in two completely different directory branches:

```
$ find ./
  foo/
  foo/setup.py
  foo/ns/
  foo/ns/__init__.py # __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  foo/ns/foo
  foo/ns/foo/__init__.py
  bar/
  bar/setup.py
  bar/ns/
  bar/ns/__init__.py # __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  bar/ns/bar/
  bar/base/bar/__init__.py
```

The reason is that with, for example,

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(...,packages=['ns.foo'],...)
```

to work, `setup.py` has to be place in the same level as the namespace package, in `foo/`, in order for it to find `ns.foo`.

Is there a way to write `setup.py` so that I can collapse the directory structure to:

```
└ ns/
└ __init__.py # __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
└ foo/
└ foo/__init__.py
└ foo/setup.py
└ bar/
└ bar/__init__.py
└ bar/setup.py
```

such that when I run each `setup.py`, it builds the respective package?